# How can I associate columns in Rails? (postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, shopify

I have 2 models:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

and

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ShopifyApp::SessionStorage
 has_many :addresses
end
```

with:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
  create_table    :addresses do |t|
   t.string      :address_1
   t.string      :address_2
   t.string      :postal
   t.string      :phone
   t.string      :city
   t.timestamps
  end
end
end
```

and

```
class CreateShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def self.up
   create_table :shops  do |t|
      t.integer :shopify_id, :limit => 8, null: false
      t.string :shopify_domain, null: false
      t.string :shopify_token, null: false
      t.jsonb :shop_json, null: false
      t.timestamps
   end

  add_index :shops, :shopify_domain, unique: true
 end

 def self.down
   drop_table :shops
 end
end
```

I would like to reference the 'shopify_id' column in the Shop table with a column called 'shopify_id' (that contains the same value) in Address table.

How could I do that?

Comment: You can use custom primary keys but it requires a lot of work arounds and is not likely worth the effort. I would just stick with the convention of an integer `id` column. http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Comment: The only case I would really consider is if you're building an app that needs to scale very large where you would use UUIDs to avoid race conditions. Otherwise you want to stick with normalized models and the principle of least suprise.

Comment: I've reformulated my problem... I want to associate 2 integers columns in different tables with rails.